# Currency symbol acting weird in magento2

Tags: magento2, currency

I am trying to display "SEK" instead of "kr" in magento2 when showing currency symbol. However, when i deselect "Use standard" it refuses if the box says "SEK" and when i save it is set at "Use standard" again and the site shows "kr" still.

If i write something else, for example: "TEST". It will display TEST instead of kr and the "Use standard" box will remain unchecked.

Do i use the setting incorrectly or might this be a bug in Magento 2?

Comment: it seems like a bug so you will get better help on github

Comment: @nenne were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a related issue 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8198

However, if you can't still use "SEK" symbol, I would recommend that you create a plugin to set the "SEK" symbol for your desired currency.

Here's a sample on what "plugin" should look like.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency">
<plugin disabled="false" name="Sample_Module::currencyfix" sortOrder="1" type="Sample\Module\Plugin\Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency" /></type>
```